# java NullPointerException when accessing a HashMap in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java

I'm encountering a 'NullPointerException' in my Java program when trying to access a 'HashMap' in a multithreaded environment. I've reviewed my code and am struggling to identify the issue.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyMultithreadedProgram 
{
  private Map<String, Integer> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

  public void updateData( String key, int value ) 
  {
    dataMap.put( key, value );
  }

  public int getData( String key ) 
  {
    return dataMap.get( key ); // NullPointerException occurs here
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) 
  {
    final MyMultithreadedProgram program = new MyMultithreadedProgram();

    // Assume some multithreading scenario here...
    // Thread 1
    new Thread( () -> {
      program.updateData( "A", 42 );
    } ).start();

    // Thread 2
    new Thread( () -> {
      int result = program.getData( "A" ); // NullPointerException happens here
      System.out.println( "Value for key A: " + result );
    } ).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Change both `int`s to `Integer` and see what happens.

Answer (score 4):

HashMap's spec clearly states that if you access it from multiple threads, it is completely broken. NPEs is one of a billion things that could happen. The fix is **not** to touch that hashmap from more than one thread.

1. Stop using multiple threads. It's unlikely to help.
2. Alternatively, use `synchronized` around blocks that should be atomic.
3. Alternatively, wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedMap`. But this cannot do anything useful other than making *single* calls atomic. It means code like `if (!map.containsKey(k)) map,put(k, v);` **is broken** (you can't make 2 calls in a row and expect them to be consistent).
4. Use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thread 2 will be executed before Thread 1 (or before it finished the `Map::put` operation), the `Map::get` returns `null`, and the attempt to unbox that to an `int` causes the `NullPointerException`.

But as @rzwitserloot says in his answer: the whole concept is broken!
Do not access bare `HashMap` instances concurrently.